# Finding the input from the impulse response and output

Tags: fourier-transform, audio

I have $y,h,x$ which are all vectors.
From $y[n]=x[n]*h[n]$    which is basically how I got $y[n]$. I also know $h[n]$.

I put this through a Fourier transform. Let's assume that the capitalized versions of those are the fourier transforms:

$Y[k]=X[k]H[k]$, then $Y[k] inv(H[k])=X[k]$

But inverse of $H$ doesn't exist because it is a vector.

How else can I solve this?

Comment: you're confusing *convolution* with a *matrix representing convolution*, and that doesn't even make much sense, because your time-domain convolution becomes point-wise multiplication in frequency domain. Tidy up your notation! That will solve your confusion; I recommend using $\cdot$ as multiplication operator instead of $*$, which is often used as convolution operator. (Also, matrices can have inverses. So what you claim isn't even true!)

Comment: Point taken about the notation. Do you mean that according to my notation it would seem like it is pointwise multiplicaiton, or is it the case that I am wrong to assume that it is a matrix multiplicaiton, and it is actually pointwise multiplication? Also, since H is a 1D vector that can't be a square unless it is 1x1, can I really have it's inverse?

Comment: a 1×1 matrix has an inverse, unless it's $0$. Anyway, $H$ is *not* a matrix, I don't even know how you come to that conclusion! And: your notation simply won't work; even if $H$ is a vector (which it actually is), your notation would imply a inner product or a convolution or something; you probably want to write something like $Y_kH^{-1}_k=X_k, k=1,2,\ldots$ to make it clear you mean point-wise multiplication. Avoid the $*$; and a product of vectors is not a point-wise product, usually.

Comment: Hi ! First of all, is this a homework, please indicate and please show your effort? Then as Marcus has outlined, you are confusing the basic notation and representation terminology. So please differentiate between 1-) discrete-time **sequences** $x[n]$ , $h[n]$, $y[n]$ and their relationship through LTI **convolution** sum as $$y[n] = x[n] \star h[n]$$  and 2-) a set of finite length vectors (**matrices**)  $x,h,y$ that hold samples of the sequences, and relations between matrices (vectors) that provide an alternate linear algebra representation of the convolution sum as $$y = H \cdot x$$.

Comment: and 3-) a third relationship by using the **Fourler** transform convolution theorem where $X,H,Y$ indicate the DTFT and DFT of the corresponding sequences and the DTFT / DFT of the output $y[n]$  is given by $$ Y(\omega) = H(\omega) X(\omega)$$ and $$Y[k] = H[k] X[k] $$ where $Y[k],H[k]$ and $X[k]$ are complex valued DFT sequences which can be represented by their vectors in a computer.

Comment: I just had some editing, I don't know if I made it right, please tell me if I did wrongly. Anyways, yes this is a homework. We were asked to find echoed audio $y[n]$ for the given audio $x[n]$ using MATLAB. To show my effort, I would have to paste MATLAB code here but I guess it would be redundant here so I am going to tell you of the steps I had for this: I found the impulse response $h[n]$ and convolved it with $x[n]$ to find $y[n]$. After doing that, we were asked to revert $y[n]$ to $x[n]$ using $h[n]$ which is where I am stuck at now.

Comment: ok. If you know the impulse response $h[n]$ of the LTI system that created the echo on $x[n]$ into $y[n]$, then can you also say that it's a perfectly **invertible** system? (i.e., $\frac{1}{H(\omega)}$ is finite for all $\omega$)

Comment: Yes it is invertible. I just checked all the values of H(w) and none of them are 0. Btw,h[n] is basically a combination of 3 impulse functions, one at 0, one at  1*frequency and another at 2*frequency